# What is remote binary in Android Studio? And what has actually been done behind the scene?

Tags: dependencies, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am new to Android Studio.  I am following a tutorial to build an android app.  Each time an external resource is required, it asks me to add an implementation line in the dependencies block in build.gradle file.  For example, when I need a tool to handle http request, I need to add the following:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1'
```

From the [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) page, it calls it **remote binary**. The format of it is        `group:name:version`.  I have searched through web, but I didn't find the definition about what is **group**, and **name**.  And where and who defines it.  Why the **group** has to be called `com.squareup.okhttp3`, not just `okhttp3`?

I want to learn what has actually been done when I build my app.  So could someone explain to me what is a `remote binary` and its breakdown?  I appreciate your help!!

Best

Answer (score 0):

**Definition of `remote binary`**:

It is called a `remote binary` because you download it from a remote repository where this binary/lib is published (i.e you don't have this binary on your computer, you need to download it)

- **Definition of `group`**:

  you can think of it like the package name for your project

And for your question "Why the group has to be called `com.squareup.okhttp3`, not just `okhttp3`?"

- because simply to avoid conflicts with other libs/binaries if their artifact matches, like:

  ```
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1'
  implementation 'com.foo.bar:okhttp:4.2.1'
  ```

here you have the same name(artifact name) for different libs, which one to download? So, it is important to include the absolute name including the group of each one

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  Although I don't quite understand your example, it seems having the group `com.squareup.okhttp3` can lower the chance of conflict than just `okhttp3`.  I generally understand it.